# Toogle cell values after button click in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Image of first toggle]I'm very basic in Excel-VBA and stuck at a problem.

My solution requires me to toggle "Yes" or "No" between two columns "Y" and "N".
During this exercise, the rows having cell values "Yes" or "No" remain fixed until edited manually BUT cannot have both Yes AND No simultaneously.
In simpler words, the code requires with every click, a toggle between Yes or No along the same row, in their designated columns.

The image shows what my first toggle does. Not Good for my solution.

My code however tends to do else. I've managed to compile. But need some help.

```vb
Sub Toggle()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10    ' Cell Range to lookup
        If Cells(i, 5).Value = "No" Then
            Cells(i, 4).Value = "Yes"
            Cells(i, 5).ClearContents ' Must clear No value before switching to Yes
        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = "No"
            Cells(i, 4).ClearContents 'Must clear Yes value before switching to No
        Exit Sub

        End If
    Next i

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. On the first yes, the code will exit because the exit sub.  Remove it and the code will work ok until the msgbox. Y have to get another solution to that msgbox

Answer (score 0):

I guess with a bit of troubleshooting, i was able to acheive the result with a simple deletion of "Exit Sub" from my code and it toggled the values in cells just how i wanted!